# Discord.JS able to add role but unable to remove role?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, discord, discord.js

I've been recently pondering this piece of code for the longest time. I am able to add the role, but the second I try removing the roles there's no errors nor does it actually remove their role.

I have tried looking up this issue on the internet, but every single one either isn't the same context or hasn't solved mine. I have also tried completely copying my add role command, and just change "`addRole`" to "`removeRole`" and that still doesn't work.

```js
// Unmute.js
/* ... */
exports.run = async(client,message,args) => {
  /* ... */
  let mutee = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
  if (!mutee) return message.channel.send("You did not mention a user!")
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
  if (!reason) reason = "No reason."
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.property === "Muted")
  if (!muterole) {
    try {
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Muted",
        color: "#514f48",
        permissions: []
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async(channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SPEAK: false
        });
      })
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e.stack)
    }
  }
  /* ... */
  mutee.removeRole(muterole.id).then(() => {
    message.delete()
    /* ... */
  });
}
```

```js
// Mute.js
/* ... */
exports.run = async(client,message,args) => {
  /* ... */
  let mutee = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
  if (!mutee) return message.channel.send("You did not mention a user!")
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
  if (!reason) reason = "No reason."
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.property === "Muted")
  if (!muterole) {
    try {
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Muted",
        color: "#514f48",
        permissions: []
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async(channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SPEAK: false
        });
      })
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e.stack)
    }
  }
  /* ... */
  mutee.addRole(muterole.id).then(() => {
    message.delete()
    /* ... */
  });
}
```

(All unnecessary parts have been cut off unless if needed)

The result I was expecting when running `%mute [user]` is to mute the user, which it does. The result I was expecting with `%unmute [user]` would of course be to unmute the user, it does not unmute the user but continues the "then" statement that should only run if it was successful with unmuting the user. There's no errors printing or anything, so I do not understand the issue one single bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```js
> let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.property === "Muted")
> ```

`property` is not a property of a [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role). Because of this, `muterole` is undefined each command execution, causing *another* "Muted" role to be created. This new role role is then used instead of the old role, leaving the user with the old role.

Compare [`Role.name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=name) for your expected behavior.

```js
let muteRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Muted")
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to find this for so long and it was right infront of me the whole time lol,